# Exporting dynamic range of sheets to a single PDF document

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to export a number of sheets (anywhere from 1 to 500), based on a cell containing a certain word ie: "Print" to a single PDF document.

Below is what I have tried doing so far, however, even though the Sheets 8,9 and 10 contain "Print" in cell A1 I still get the message "PDF file not created".

```
Sub Save_Sheets_As_PDF()

Dim sheetsInPDF As Long
Dim replaceSelected As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim PDFfileName As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook

        sheetsInPDF = 0
        replaceSelected = True
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If LCase(ws.Range("A1").Value) = "Print" Then
                ws.Select replaceSelected
                replaceSelected = False
                sheetsInPDF = sheetsInPDF + 1
            End If
        Next
            
        If sheetsInPDF > 0 Then
            PDFfileName = Worksheets("QUOTE").Range("B6") & ".pdf"
            .ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFfileName, _
                Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            MsgBox "Created '" & PDFfileName & "' containing " & sheetsInPDF & " Elevations"
        Else
            MsgBox "PDF file not created"
        End If
        
        .Worksheets(1).Select True
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Even if it may be best to replace this code completely.
TIA.
Brad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code...

```
If LCase(ws.Range("A1").Value) = "Print" Then
```

...will always be evaluated to False.  Try the following instead...

```
If LCase(ws.Range("A1").Value) = "print" Then
```

To specify the path, try...

```
PDFfileName = .Path & "\" & Worksheets("QUOTE").Range("B6") & ".pdf"
```

Actually, if Worksheets("QUOTE") is located within ThisWorkbook, try the following instead...

```
PDFfileName = .Path & "\" & .Worksheets("QUOTE").Range("B6") & ".pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Domenic. Silly error on my part. I have corrected this now, but get a Run-time '1004' error. I assume this is because I have not specified a file path? Is there a way to just use the same file location as the main sheet? Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Domenic. I figured out what my issue was with the Run-time error. I had an invalid character in the Cell 'B6'. So your answers worked perfectly once I amended that.